# add product quantity input modifier in woocommerce mini-cart.php

Tags: php, woocommerce, storefront

in the woocommerce mini-cart I'd like to display an input to adjust the quantity of each product.

I added line in the mini-cart.php file of my Storefront child theme (using the function `woocommerce_quantity_input`), it displays the input, but the cart is not 'updated'.
Any idea how to do this?

See the last line of:

```
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            $_product     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
            $product_id   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

            if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
                $product_name      = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                $thumbnail         = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                $product_price     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                $product_permalink = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', $_product->is_visible() ? $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ) : '', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                ?>
                <li class="woocommerce-mini-cart-item <?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_mini_cart_item_class', 'mini_cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">

                    <?php
                    //split product name and color
                    $pattern = '/ [^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+| –/';
                    $matches = array();
                    $dummy = preg_match($pattern, $product_name, $matches);
                    $posi = strpos($product_name, $matches[0]);
                    $productnamename = substr($product_name, 0, $posi);
                    $dashAndProductcolor    = substr($product_name, $posi);
                    ?>
                    <?php if ( empty( $product_permalink ) ) : ?>
                        <?php echo $thumbnail; ?>
                        <?php echo '<span class="minicart-prod-name">'.$productnamename.'</span><br/>' ?>
                        <?php echo '<span class="minicart-prod-color">'.$dashAndProductcolor.'</span>' ?>
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $product_permalink ); ?>">
                            <?php echo $thumbnail; ?>
                            <?php echo '<span class="minicart-prod-name">'.$productnamename.'</span><br/>' ?>
                            <?php echo wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item ); ?>
                            <?php echo '<span class="minicart-prod-color">'.$dashAndProductcolor.'</span>' ?>
                        </a>
                        <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_quantity', '<span class="each-price">' . sprintf( '%s', $product_price ) . '</span>', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_quantity', '<span class="quantity">' . sprintf( '%s', $cart_item['quantity'] ) . '</span>', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); ?>
<?php 
echo woocommerce_quantity_input( array('input_value' => $cart_item['quantity']),$cart_item['data'], false );
?>
```

Comment: Adding the input where you did is simply going to add the input. What code or action have you added to catch the input change and update the cart values? Maybe take a look at the WC_Cart object as a starting point.

Comment: It should requires some additional jQuery code + Ajax to update quantities in minicart.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answers. Maybe I should use this plugin to avoid too much work : https://gumroad.com/l/wbupro. What do you think?